# Install-module is not recognized PowerShell

Tags: powershell

[image: скрин консоли]

[image: версия powershell]

Вывод из консоли при попытке установить модуль. У меня windows 10 и powershell 5.1. Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы узнать причину недоступности команды `Install-Module`, необходимо попытаться вручную загрузить модуль:

```
Import-Module -Name PowerShellGet
```

Если ругается на ExecutionPolicy, то `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`